# Error while loading AnnotatedElement and CharSequence while running Scala and Java on macOS

Tags: java, macos, scala

I am trying to run Stanford NLP Topic Modelling Toolbox along with the Scala script.
macOS: 10.13.5
Scala: 2.12.6
Java: 8 (JDK: 1.8.0_161)
I have already checked the Scala documentation and both the versions of Java and Scala are compatible.

Still, every time I run `java -jar tmt-0.4.0.jar example-0-test.scala` I run into this error:
`error: error while loading CharSequence, class file '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar(java/lang/CharSequence.class)' is broken
(bad constant pool tag 18 at byte 10)
error: error while loading AnnotatedElement, class file '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar(java/lang/reflect/AnnotatedElement.class)' is broken
(bad constant pool tag 18 at byte 76)`

I could not find an answer in similar questions other than downgrading or upgrading either of the two, which is not the case for me since both versions are officially compatible.

Please help me with this.

Edit: I tried downgrading to Java 7 but it still gives the same error.